# remote Powershell script Scheduled task

Tags: monitoring, powershell, hyper-v, remote-access, replication

I am having trouble running a Powershell script as a scheduled task.  The script remotely logs into two Hyper-V hosts, queries the replication status and emails the result back to me.
The script works fine when I run it manually, either in Powershell ISE or by running the script directly, however when I run it as a scheduled task the task gets stuck in a running state and  I never get a result.

I've checked my scheduled task setup is working correctly by replacing the script with one that simply writes a text file to a local folder so it's not that.  I'm also logged in as the same user as the task runs under when I manually run the script so it's no that, what am I missing?

Here's my script:

```
$array = @("host1.domain.com", "host2.domain.com")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {

     $pass = cat C:\Scripts\Creds.txt | convertto-securestring
     $mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "username",$pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $array[$i] -Credential $mycred -FilePath "C:\Scripts\Check_VMReplication.ps1"
}
```

The script calls another script in the same folder:

```
$hstname = Hostname
$Replication = Get-VMReplication
$MessageFail = $hstname + ' Replication Alert'
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.server.com'

hostname > C:\Scripts\iveremoted.txt

for ($i=0; $i -lt $Replication.length; $i++) {

        $MessageBody = $hstname+ " has reported a replication status of " + $Replication.health[$i] + ' for server ' + $Replication.name[$i]
        $FailMessageSubject = $Replication.name[$i] + " Replication Alert"
        if ($Replication.health[$i] -ne 'Normal') {

         send-mailmessage -to "mail@address.com>" -from 'frommail@address.com' -subject $MessageFail  -body $MessageBody -smtpServer $SmtpServer
    }
    else{
        send-mailmessage -to "mail@address.com" -from 'frommail@address.com' -subject 'Everything's OK'  -body $MessageBody -smtpServer $SmtpServer
    }

}
```

The script appears not to be able to log on because the iveremoted.txt file doesn't get written to the remote machine.

Any idea on what I might have missed?

Comment: Maybe a problem with user rights? Have you tried "execute with highest privilegs"? Has the user under which you run the script enough rights on your System?

Comment: Run with Highest Privileges is set and the script is running as a user who is part of the admin group.

Comment: Then pls also try to uncheck the "highest priv..." option... and run it again...

Comment: Try to add `echo $? >>c:\path\to\somefile.txt` just after the `Invoke-Command` Cmdlet just to see if it executes successfuly.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if I run the Check_VMReplication.ps1 code using Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {} instead of a second script file it runs fine.  I guess I'll just have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but if I run the Check_VMReplication.ps1 code using

```
Invoke-Command  -Credential $mycred -ScriptBlock {CODE GOES HERE}
```

instead of a second script file it runs fine. I guess I'll just have to do it that way.